# Python Detecting two of the same things in a string

Tags: python

```
while testcount < 100:  
   num1=randint(0,10)
   num2=randint(0,10)
   num3=randint(0,10)
   num4=randint(0,10)
   num5=randint(0,10)
   numo=[num1,num2,num3,num4,num5]

   if #there are two 7s# in numo:
      testcount=testcount+1
      num_of_successes=num_of_successes+1
   else:
      testcount=testcount+1

    print(num_of_successes,"out of 100 there were two 7s")
```

How do i detect if there are two 7s in 'numo'?
even if it doesn't use much of this code.

Comment: you want to see if there is two 7s  in the numo

Answer (score 5):

For a list, you can use the `count()` function to find out how many elements of the `parameter` passed in to count function exist in the list.

Example -

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,4]
>>> l.count(4)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid searching the item in the list by counting on the fly without any list at all:

```
from random import randint

num_of_successes = 0

for testcount in xrange(100):
    if sum(int(randint(0, 10) == 7) for i in xrange(5)) == 2:
       num_of_successes += 1

print(num_of_successes, "out of 100 there were two 7s")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list.count()` method to check the occurances.

```
while testcount < 100:  
       num1=randint(0,10)
       num2=randint(0,10)
       num3=randint(0,10)
       num4=randint(0,10)
       num5=randint(0,10)

   numo=[num1,num2,num3,num4,num5]


   num_of_successes=numo.count(7)

   if num_of_successe == 2 : 
     print(num_of_successes,"out of 100 there were two 7s")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for testcount in range(100):
   num1=randint(0,10)
   num2=randint(0,10)
   num3=randint(0,10)
   num4=randint(0,10)
   num5=randint(0,10)
   numo=[num1,num2,num3,num4,num5]

   if numo.count(7) == 2:
      num_of_successes=num_of_successes+1

print(num_of_successes, " out of 100 there were two 7s")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it:

```
from random import randint
testcount = 0
num_of_successes = 0
while testcount < 100:
    num1 = randint(0, 10)
    num2 = randint(0, 10)
    num3 = randint(0, 10)
    num4 = randint(0, 10)
    num5 = randint(0, 10)
    numo = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
    if numo.count(7) == 2:
        num_of_successes += 1
    testcount += 1
print num_of_successes, "out of 100 there were two 7s"
```